# What is Oracle equivalent data masking logic for SQL Server's "FUNCTION = 'default()'"

Tags: oracle, data-masking

In Microsoft SQL Server, we write below ALTER statement to mask a particular column:

```sql
ALTER TABLE [Table_Name]
ALTER COLUMN YEAR_CODE ADD MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'default()');
```

Currently I am working on Oracle and trying the replicate the same in Oracle to mask a column.

In Oracle SQL Developer the above command is giving the error as:

> Error report -
> ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option
> 01735. 00000 -  "invalid ALTER TABLE option"
> *Cause:
> *Action:

Whereas I expect Success message in Output window of Oracle.
Can anybody help me to convert the above statement in Oracle as this statement does not work on Oracle SQL Developer.

Comment: You appear to be under the impression you can take one dialect of SQL and "dump" it into a completely different product, that uses a *different* dialect, and expect it to *just work*; it won't. You need to translate to the appropriate dialect for the RDBMS you are using.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dmksb/data_masking.html#GUID-E3C164DC-0004-4857-A038-54EC7B1A5118 read , try , post specific issues if any.

Comment: and also https://blogs.oracle.com/cloudsecurity/post/columnlevel-security-oracle-databases-data-redaction